# Angular 6 : Update a value in my component when she change in my service

Tags: angular, typescript, service, components

My goal is simple in principle, but I can not put it in place: **I want one of my components to be updated when the variable of a service is changed.**

To better explain my problem, **here is an example :**

*Here, I have a service that increases or decreases a number of points.
It decreases or increases this number of points when it receives a call to one of its functions.
It also says if this variable is even or odd*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {
  Number: number = 0;
  IsOdd: boolean = false;

  constructor() {}

  IncreaseNumber() {
    this.Number = this.Number + 1;
    this.IsOdd = !this.IsOdd;
  }

  DecreaseNumber() {
    this.Number = this.Number - 1;
    this.IsOdd = !this.IsOdd;
  }
}
```

*Here, I have my component, which needs to know if my figure is even or odd.

At initialization, no problem! It knows it!

How, every time the number changes in my service (test.service.ts) then I make sure that the value pair/import changes in my component (test.component.ts)?*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from '../test.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  IsOdd: boolean = false;

  constructor(MyService: TestService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.IsOdd = MyService.IsOdd;
  }

}
```

**How should I do it ?**

Did my component need to `subscribe` to my service in some way?
Or Did I have to use one function like `ngOnInit` but for update?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The component "needs to know" for what kind of purpose? Do you need to be notified to do some additional processing, or do you only need to update the view?

Comment: How did you know that it does not work ? means what did you implement to test your service methods ?

Comment: you need to use `Subject` from rxjs in your service and expose it as an Observable in your service. Then in your component you need to subscribe to that Observable of your service. Then you need to emit a new value through the Subject like `subject.next({val: this.Number, IsOdd : this.IsOdd })` in your service method `IncreaseNumber` and the others. When ever any change occurs in your service you will get the update in your component subscription.

Comment: First, thank for the Subject, I will look at this.
He needed for additionnel processing

Again, I put this example as simple as possible. My real case is more complex and messy. Using a simple and trivial example allow peoples to answer more easily and other people, with the same problem as me, to understand the answer better.


I know that the example does'nt work because nothings make him update

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would have automatically updated if these service variables were of a complex type like an Object or an Array as these are reference types. But since you have Service variables of type number and boolean, these will not be updated automatically as they are primitive types and hence passed by value.

So you'll have to use `BehaviorSubject`s and expose them `asObservable`s. You'll update the values of these `BehaviorSubject`s by calling the `next` method on them. Here's how:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {
  private myNumberValue = 0;
  private isOddValue = false;
  private myNumber: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(this.myNumberValue);
  private isOdd: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  myNumber$: Observable<number> = this.myNumber.asObservable();
  isOdd$:  Observable<boolean> = this.isOdd.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  increaseNumber() {
    this.myNumberValue = this.myNumberValue + 1;
    this.myNumber.next(this.myNumberValue);
    this.isOddValue = !this.isOddValue;
    this.isOdd.next(this.isOddValue);
  }

  decreaseNumber() {
    this.myNumberValue = this.myNumberValue - 1;
    this.myNumber.next(this.myNumberValue);
    this.isOddValue = !this.isOddValue;
    this.isOdd.next(this.isOddValue);
  }
}
```

Now in your Component, all you need to do is `subscribe` to the `public`ly exposed `Observable` values from the Service:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from '../test.service'
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  isOdd: boolean;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private testService: TestService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.testService.isOdd$.subscribe(isOdd => this.isOdd = isOdd);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription && this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Now since you've `subscribe`d to `isOdd$` in `ngOnInit` which gets called during component initialization, `isOdd` on your Component will update every time there is a change in the `isOddValue` in the service.

Also since this is a custom `subscription` it should be assigned to a property in the Component(`subscription`) which would be of type `Subscription` which is what we get from the `subscribe` method as a return value. We will have to call `unsubscribe` on it in `ngOnDestroy` to avoid memory leaks.

**PS:** Property and method names in Angular Classes should be in lowerCamelCase according to [**Angular's Styleguide**](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-03-04).

> Do use lower camel case to name properties and methods.

Comment: It can be achieved using `Subject` also . And it's good to use `unsubscribe` in the component during `ngOndestroy ` to avoid memory leak

Comment: Thanks, it help a lot. And I think it will help a lot of other peoples since the example is pretty simple ! ^^

Answer (score 1):

For what you are saying to work, you should be increasing/decreasing the `number` in the service within the TestComponent, not in other components.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from '../test.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  IsOdd: boolean = false;

  constructor(MyService: TestService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.IsOdd = MyService.IsOdd;
  }

  increase() {
    MyService.IncreaseNumber();
  }

  decrease() {
    MyService.DecreaseNumber();
  }

  getIsOdd() {
    return MyService.IsOdd;
  }

}
```

Comment: It was an example, 
I tried to figure out a simple example to explain my problem. Because with my work, these things would get messy and complicated ^^

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions you can use including setting up an Observable to subscribe to changes. These are all valid solutions.

The simplest solution would be to bind to the service in the template rather than the value:

```
<div> {{ MyService.IsOdd }} </div>
```

In `ngOnInit`, you are assigning the boolean *value* to a property on the component. This value never changes. In order to create a data binding and respond to changes, you have to bind a reference to a property using an object which requires a `.` Thus, the `MyService.IsOdd` will work in the template.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rktij7

Comment: Thanks, it was the method is used at first. 
But I could'nt stop thinking "what if I needed to see it without  using it directly in the html".
So i was looking for the other method ^^

Answer (score 0):

Observable is a great way to do it.

Another easy way and in my opinion much simpler is to emit an event whenever the `IncreaseNumber` or `DecreaseNumber` methods are called in the `TestService`.

Then, in the constructor of your `TestComponent` you can subscribe to the event you created in the TestService and then update your `IsOdd` field (or any other field you wish to update in your component). This subscription is possible because an event is a wrapper for observable.

Like so: 
Firstly, Create an event emitter in your service

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class TestService {
      Number: number = 0;
      IsOdd: boolean = false;
      EmitIsOdd = new EventEmitter<any>();

      constructor() {}

      IncreaseNumber() {
        this.Number = this.Number + 1;
        this.IsOdd = !this.IsOdd;
        this.EmitIsOdd.emit();
      }

      DecreaseNumber() {
        this.Number = this.Number - 1;
        this.IsOdd = !this.IsOdd;
        this.EmitIsOdd.emit();
      }
    }
```

Then Subscribe to the event in your Component constructor

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { TestService } from '../test.service'

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-test',
      templateUrl: './test.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
    })

    export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

      IsOdd: boolean = false;

      constructor(MyService: TestService) {
        this.MyService.EmitIsOdd.subscribe(
          () => {
            this.IsOdd = this.MyService.IsOdd;
          }    
        );
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.IsOdd = MyService.IsOdd;
      }
    }
```

There you go, simple and effective.